# What does this icon that looks like an askew wireless symbol mean in Calendar?

Tags: macos, ical, sharing

I have iCal synced with Google Calendar and would like one of my accounts to also sync with iCal.  In order to fix this problem I am trying to understand what the icon in two and three below mean. What do these icons indicate?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon means that the calendar is being shared. Click the icon for details:

[image]